# diff strings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, diff

I have a pandas dataframe full of strings (300k) similar to this.

| index | original | modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | This is the original sentence | This is the changed sentence |
| 1 | This is a different sentence | This is the same sentence |

and I want to diff the strings.
Ideally I'd create a third one with the changes such as:

| index | original | modified | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | This is the original sentence | This is the changed sentence | *original* -> **changed** |
| 1 | This is a different sentence | This is the same sentence | *a different* -> **the same** |

But even just being able to output the differences would already be great.

I tried df.applying

```
difflib.ndiff()
```

but it outputs

```
<generator object Differ.compare at 0x7ff8121a...
```

Comment: Did you even try to look at what the generator generates when you iterate over its output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether `difflib` has a shrink-wrapped way to do what you want, but it definitely has some ingredients to work with.

Here's an example of what you can do with `SequenceMatcher` from `difflib` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-examples)):

```py
records = [
    {'original':'This is the original sentence', 'modified':'This is the changed sentence'},
    {'original':'This is a different sentence', 'modified':'This is the same sentence'}
]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(df)

import difflib
def getDiff(o, m):
    diffStr = ''
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, o, m)
    for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in sm.get_opcodes():
        diffStr += '\n' if diffStr else ''
        diffStr += f'{tag:7} o[{i1}:{i2}] --> m[{j1}:{j2}] {o[i1:i2]!r:>6} --> {m[j1:j2]!r}'
    return f"original: {o}\nmodified: {m}\n" + diffStr


out = df.apply(lambda x: getDiff(x['original'], x['modified']), axis=1)
[print(x) for x in out]
```

Output:

```
                        original                      modified
0  This is the original sentence  This is the changed sentence
1   This is a different sentence     This is the same sentence
original: This is the original sentence
modified: This is the changed sentence
equal   o[0:12] --> m[0:12] 'This is the ' --> 'This is the '
replace o[12:15] --> m[12:16]  'ori' --> 'chan'
equal   o[15:16] --> m[16:17]    'g' --> 'g'
replace o[16:20] --> m[17:19] 'inal' --> 'ed'
equal   o[20:29] --> m[19:28] ' sentence' --> ' sentence'
original: This is a different sentence
modified: This is the same sentence
equal   o[0:8] --> m[0:8] 'This is ' --> 'This is '
insert  o[8:8] --> m[8:13]     '' --> 'the s'
equal   o[8:9] --> m[13:14]    'a' --> 'a'
replace o[9:14] --> m[14:15] ' diff' --> 'm'
equal   o[14:15] --> m[15:16]    'e' --> 'e'
delete  o[15:19] --> m[16:16] 'rent' --> ''
equal   o[19:28] --> m[16:25] ' sentence' --> ' sentence'
```

The `replace`, `insert` and `delete` opcodes could help you do what you're asking. However, note that `"original"` and `"changed"` get compared at a character-by-character level (so that the letter `"g"` in both words is detected as being unchanged), so it may take some additional work to get to the exact sample output in your question.

**UPDATED**:
I've thought about this a bit more (since it's certainly an appealing capability to build onto `difflib`) and have come up with a strategy that uses `get_op_codes()` from `SequenceMatcher` to give the exact "changed" output specified in the example in the question. I don't know that it would give satisfying results for every possible example, but the same can be said of many problems and solutions:

```py
records = [
    {'original':'This is the original sentence', 'modified':'This is the changed sentence'},
    {'original':'This is a different sentence', 'modified':'This is the same sentence'}
]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(df)

import difflib
def getDiff(o, m):
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, o, m)
    oStart, mStart, oEnd, mEnd = None, None, None, None
    for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in sm.get_opcodes():
        if tag != 'equal':
            if oStart is None:
                oStart, mStart = i1, j1
            oEnd, mEnd = i2, j2
    diffStr = '<no change>' if oStart is None else o[oStart:oEnd] + ' -> ' + m[mStart:mEnd]
    return diffStr

df['changed'] = df.apply(lambda x: getDiff(x['original'], x['modified']), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                        original                      modified
0  This is the original sentence  This is the changed sentence
1   This is a different sentence     This is the same sentence
                        original                      modified                  changed
0  This is the original sentence  This is the changed sentence      original -> changed
1   This is a different sentence     This is the same sentence  a different -> the same
```

**UPDATE #3**:
OK, now for a solution that treats punctuation, white space and string boundaries as word delimiters and decides whether or not to merge opcodes with `tag == 'equal'` into adjacent diffs depending on whether they are standalone (i.e., bordered by "string boundaries").

I have added a more complex example to illustrate what it does. I have also wrapped all result substrings in single quotes for clarity.

```py
records = [
    {'original':'This, my good friend, is a very small piece of cake', 'modified':'That, my friend, is a very, very large piece of work'},
    {'original':'This is the original sentence', 'modified':'This is the changed sentence'},
    {'original':'This is a different sentence', 'modified':'This is the same sentence'}
]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(df.to_string(index=False))

import difflib
import string
def isStandalone(x, i1, i2):
    puncAndWs = string.punctuation + string.whitespace
    while i1 < i2 and x[i1] in puncAndWs:
        i1 += 1
    while i1 < i2 and x[i2 - 1] in puncAndWs:
        i2 -= 1
    return (i1 == 0 or x[i1 - 1] in puncAndWs) and (i2 == len(x) or x[i2] in puncAndWs)
def makeDiff(o, m, oStart, oEnd, mStart, mEnd):
    oChange = "'" + o[oStart:oEnd] + "'"
    mChange = "'" + m[mStart:mEnd] + "'"
    return '<no change>' if oStart is None else oChange + ' -> ' + mChange
def getDiff(o, m):
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, o, m)
    diffList = []
    oStart, mStart, oEnd, mEnd = None, None, None, None
    for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in sm.get_opcodes():
        bothStandalone = isStandalone(o, i1, i2) and isStandalone(m, j1, j2)
        if bothStandalone:
            if oStart is not None:
                if tag == 'equal':
                    diffList.append(makeDiff(o, m, oStart, oEnd, mStart, mEnd))
                    oStart, mStart, oEnd, mEnd = None, None, None, None
                else:
                    oEnd, mEnd = i2, j2
            elif tag != 'equal':
                oStart, mStart = i1, j1
                oEnd, mEnd = i2, j2
        elif oStart is not None:
            oEnd, mEnd = i2, j2
        else:
            oStart, mStart = i1, j1
            oEnd, mEnd = i2, j2
    if oStart is not None:
        diffList.append(makeDiff(o, m, oStart, oEnd, mStart, mEnd))
    diffStr = ', '.join(diffList)
    return diffStr

df['changed'] = df.apply(lambda x: getDiff(x['original'], x['modified']), axis=1)
#print(df.to_string(index=False))

df.drop(['original', 'modified'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
                                           original                                             modified
This, my good friend, is a very small piece of cake That, my friend, is a very, very large piece of work
                      This is the original sentence                         This is the changed sentence
                       This is a different sentence                            This is the same sentence
                                                                      changed
'This' -> 'That', ' good' -> '', ' small' -> ', very large', 'cake' -> 'work'
                                                      'original' -> 'changed'
                                                  'a different' -> 'the same'
```

Comment: @Tiago Moreira Did this answer help with your question?